# “Your” as a third person possessive pronoun. Is that a thing?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, possessive-pronouns

> **Your** book suggests that animals have thought processes, emotions, and social connections that are as important to them as they are to us

This is a snippet of [this article](https://www.google.com.br/amp/s/api.nationalgeographic.com/distribution/public/amp/animals/article/150714-animal-dog-thinking-feelings-brain-science?espv=1) I found on internet and the “your” at the beginning refers to Carl Safina's book *Beyond words: How animals think and feel*. Is this a real thing in formal English or a more informal thing? Or could it even be an error by the author of the article?

Comment: What do you think is unusual about it? It looks totally normal to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is, by implication, an interview with the author, with the journalist's questions in bold type.

> Speaking from Stony Brook University... he explains...

The first question begins with the reference to 'your book'.

Comment: To be clear, **your** is used exactly as expected, a *second*-person pronoun.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks.